# Spring mvc - which layer should convert entities to dtos (and vice versa)

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, api-design, dto

In which layer should DTO/Entity conversion take place.

Having following structure in a Spring Mvc application:

- Controller
- Service
- Repository

The approach I'm using now, where service layer is `@Transactional`.

```
@RestController
public class ExampleController {

    @Autowired
    private ExampleService exampleService;

    @Autowired
    private ExampleMapper exampleMapper;

    @GetMapping("/examples")
    public ResponseEntity<List<ExamleDto>> getAll() {
        var examples = exampleService.getAll();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(exampleMapper.examplesToExampleDtos(examples));
    }

    @PostMapping("/examples")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> create(@RequestBody @Valid ExampleCreateDto createDto) {
        var example = exampleService.create(createDto)
        return ResponseEntity.created(URI.create("examples/" + example.getId()).build();
    }

   // PUT, DELETE, ...
}
```

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ExampleService {

    @Autowired
    private ExampleRepository exampleRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ExampleMapper exampleMapper;

    public List<Examle> getAll() {
        var examples = exampleRepository.findAll();
        return examples;
    }

   public void create(ExampleDto exampleDto) {
       var example = exampleMapper.asExample(exampleDto);
       return exampleRepository.save(example);
   }

}
```

```
public interface ExampleRepository extends JpaRepository<Example, Long> {
```

Why I choose this aproach:

The service layer is transactional, so whenever we get back to the controller, all changes will be flushed (version field for example) will all be set.

It makes you think about your entitygraph, lets say you have a Person entity which has a list of Deparments. Lets say the PersonDto contains also the list of DeparmentDtos, it forces you to fetch all deparments before hand or you will run into a LazyInitializationException in the controller layer.
Which in my opinion is a good thing, because if you would perform the mapping in the service you would be doing N + 1 queries (N being the number of deparments) without realizing it.

Services who need each other to perform there business tasks, work on the entity model instead of the DTO model, which might have some validation (@NotNull, @Size, ...) which only supposed to be valided when it comes from the outside, but internally not all validations should be applied.
Business rules will still be checked in the service layer as part of the service method.
The only thing here is that for update/creates service still communicate by passing dtos iso of entities.

I googled this topic a lot, but couldn't find a definitive answer.

Comment: Consider that there might be different DTO types for different use cases or transports (HTTP vs. messaging, two different versions of an API). The DTO format is specific to your Web tier and should be handled entirely within it.

Comment: DTOs are for external world (sending customized data depending on the service you are interacting with) whereas Entities for DAO layer (database layer) only (limited modifications).

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- meaning all the mapping should be done in the controller ? and service only accepts entities then?